# Enviar email usando NetOffice ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, envio-de-email

Estou a iniciar-me no envio de emails na minha aplicação, para tal estou a tentar usar a *package* do [NetOffice](https://github.com/CaioProiete/NetOffice-NuGet) para enviar e receber emails. O que estou a tentar fazer é: A partir da conta logada no pc local com a aplicação do Outlook, envio um email com uma mensagem pré-definida na minha aplicação.

Logo ao início estou a ter problemas... Estou a seguir um [exemplo](http://netoffice.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Outlook_Example04) do NetOffice onde me dá logo erros, onde ao fazer o import da package (`using NetOffice;`), dá erros a iniciar o Outlook (`Outlook.Application outlookApplication = new Outlook.Application();`).

Outra pequena dúvida:
 Existem packages ou melhores alternativas ao NetOffice?

Comment: Qual é o problema? Você pode inserir o código?

Comment: O único código que coloquei foi a iniciar o outlook (`Outlook.Application outlookApplication = new Outlook.Application();`)

Answer (score 1):

Baixar Package pelo Nuget do Visual Studio e trazer para o seu projeto as dependências necessário seguindo os passos:

*Menu:* **TOOLS -> Nuget Package Manager -> Manage Nuget Packages For Solution**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois com ele aberto fazer pesquisa (**netoffice.outlook**):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
*Obs: Escolha a versão correspondente ao seu Framework no meu caso foi 4.5, a descrição já fala por si (2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0 e 4.5)*

Após a instalação com sucesso a codificação no seu projeto seria assim:

```
NetOffice.OutlookApi._Application app = new NetOffice.OutlookApi._Application();            
app.Session.SendAndReceive(true);
```

Um dica legal é sempre utilizar o **NuGet** sempre que possível, pois, o mesmo resolve dependências.
Um boa leitura sobre o [assunto](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/visualstudiobr/acelere-seu-desenvolvimento-com-o-nuget), e neste site.